# Meteor Differential Boilerplate - need for compatibility file and when to use bootstrap package

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I was looking at [Differential's meteor-boilerplate app](https://github.com/Differential/meteor-boilerplate) and noticed that they do not use a bootstrap package and also saw a directory/file in the client directory that is related - client/compatibility/bootstrap.js

I was wondering if anyone had an explanation for why/when you'd want to avoid using a package like [twbs:bootstrap](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap) and when you'd need to create a compatibility file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it's the lazy path to include external libraries in a Meteor application.

You basically have two ways to achieve this include:

1. The road of glory. Create a package (`meteor create --package`), clone the source inside it, then edit and "Meteorize" the source (declare package-scoped variables instead of window-scoped, ...). You can then publish this package on Atmosphere so that others can benefit of it.
2. Copy/paste everything in a `client/compatibility` folder.

As explained in [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp), everything in this folder is not embraced with an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) and is executed before the other code files.

When you have the time to, be brave and take the heroes path.